# Populating Dojo AccordionContainer

Tags: javascript, accordion, dojo, accordionpane

This code generates an array length of children in an accordion style

```
require(["dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(AccordionContainer, ContentPane){
    var aContainer = new AccordionContainer({style:"height: 300px"}, "markup");
    len = dataArray.length;
    for ( var i =0; i<len; i++);
    {
    aContainer.addChild(new ContentPane({
        title:dataArray[i].title,
        content: dataArray[i].content
    }));
    }
    aContainer.startup();
});
```

I am trying to populate the content part of each child. For instance, let's assume I have a list of 10 things to add to the content area. How do i populate the content area with this list(thinking of a for loop but just not sure how to implement it), and also possibly add a checkbox beside each item in the list, and then a button at the end. For example, let's assume the title of the of the contentpane is Cars. Once Cars is clicked, a list of car models will appear in accordion style with a checkbox beside it. A "Buy" button will be at the bottom of the content area to be clicked once specific cars are selected. I am new to Dojo. Been stuck on this for a while. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand well, you want to dynamically fill the content of a single `ContentPane`? Or do you want to dynamically create the `ContentPane`'s (like the answer of [Miriam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24504561/1915448) is describing).

If you're interested in dynamically adding checkboxes to your contentpane and adding a button to it, the best thing you could do is create your own widget and use a store to represent the data.

For example:

```
var FacetPane = declare("dijit/layout/FacetPane", [ ContentPane ], {
    store: null,
    labelAttr: 'name',
    _setStoreAttr: function(store) {
        this.store = store;
        this.update();
    },
    _getStoreAttr: function() {
        return this.store;   
    },
    postCreate: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.itemNode = domConstruct.create("div", {
            class: "itemNode"   
        }, this.domNode);
        this.update();
    },
    _destroyItems: function() {
        if (this.itemNode) {
            console.log("Destroying items");
            arr.forEach(registry.findWidgets(this.itemNode), function(item) {
                console.log("Destroy item : " + item.id);
                item.destroy(); 
            });
        }
    },
    update: function() {
        if (this.store) {
            this._destroyItems();
            this.store.query({}).forEach(lang.hitch(this, this._updateRecord));   
        }
        new Button({
            label: "Buy"
        }, domConstruct.create("button", null, this.itemNode));
    },
    _updateRecord: function(item) {
        var row = domConstruct.create("div", {
            class: "rowNode"   
        }, this.itemNode);
        new CheckBox({
            label: item[this.labelAttr]
        }, domConstruct.create("input", null, row));
        domConstruct.create("label", {
            innerHTML: item[this.labelAttr]
        }, row);
    }
});
```

I know, this might look like a lot of code, but what happens is quite easy. I created my own wiget called `FacetPane` which inherits from a `ContentPane`. This new module has two properties:

- store: The store containing the items that should be "converted" to checkboxes
- labelAttr: The attribute of each element in the store that should be used as the label of the checkbox

Then I override the `postCreate()` function and tell it to create an extra sub-DOMnode that will contain our items and after that I update it based on the items inside the store (which you can find in the `update()`) function.

For each item in the store (`_updateRecord()`) I add a new row node containing a checkbox and a label.

This solution can probably be improved a lot, but this should give you a basic idea of how you could create such a widget. The basic idea is to have a store for your model data and to dynamically create DOM nodes and widgets based on the store values.

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LaLNH/

Comment: Hello, could you please help resolve this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522240/dojo-accordion-style-population
Thanks.

Comment: @user3078335 isn't that exactly the same as you asked in this question? I mean, the screenshot you took is even from my example... .

Comment: Yeah, it is. I guess didn't the ask question right the first time around. The other question with the lists was more detailed and it was what I really wanted help with.I tried hacking this answer you provided to get the results but it wasn't really working properly, so I decided to re-ask it hoping i can get more help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my fiddle. Thats a way how you can atomatically populate an AccordianContainer with a number of ContentPanes of your choice. The number in this Example belongs to the Items stored in the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/6kcSr/

```
 array.forEach(DataArray, function (cars, i) {

    aContainer.addChild(new ContentPane({
        title: cars,
        content: "<input id='mycheck"+i+"' name='mycheck' data-dojo-type='dijit/form/CheckBox' checked /><label for='mycheck'>I agree</label> to try a " +cars
    }));
});
```

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Hello,
could you help me resolve this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522240/dojo-accordion-style-population
Thanks.